# ExtremeCap U3, RECentral, and El Capitan

Tags: macos, streaming

I recently upgraded to El Capitan and RECentral, the streaming application I use to play my Wii U on my iMac, no longer starts up reliably. Sometimes it just beachballs for 10 minutes until an image is displayed.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they just put up a new firmware for the Extremecap U3. Recentral now launches immediately for me. Also - after I updating the firmware - the beta version stopped working. I went back to version 1.2.15 and all is well.

Comment: I had to click "show preview window" to see the capture. Other than that, the update seems to work as expected.

Comment: After the firmware update it started working for me, too. I now have the problem that every few minutes the picture hangs for 1-2 seconds. It seems to be random and it very annoying. Does someone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, for now. I think the only fix is to wait until the RECentral starts up, until we get an update from Avermedia.

Comment: I've noticed that if I start RECentral without plugging in the HDMI input. It starts up pretty reliably. It just takes 5-8 minutes. Once the application is started. I plug in the HDMI cable and it works. Still pretty wonky though.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news. Avermedia not working on fix for El Capitan compatibility https://twitter.com/michalcerny/status/662779009869156352

Answer (score 1):

Looks like El Cap 10.11 support is indeed coming but has been delayed. Just received this from support:

"We are truly sorry for the delay regarding RECentral for Mac OSX 10.11 El Capitan 
release. 
The reason for this partially is because for this new software we also have to prepare a 
totally new firmware. 
Our engineers are working on final improvements at the moment, 
the expected release is due to the second half of this January.

Thank you very much for your understanding! 
Best regards 
AVerMedia Support"

Answer (score 0):

The beta version don't work for me. I installed Windows through Bootcamp as temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a firmware update release for the ExtremeCap U3 for El Capitan.  The only problem is it seems that if you update to this (I have not tried it yet), you'll be locked into using the device only with your Mac.  If this would be an issue for you, you may want to hold off until they come up with a more general update that supports Windows and Mac both.

http://gamerzone.avermedia.com//support/download/extremecap_u3

Comment: OK, I installed the firmware update that is supposed to allow us to use the device with El Capitan.  The Mac itself does recognize it, because I can see my video source in the RECentral preview window, but I cannot get OBS Studio (the new name for OBS Multiplatform, BTW) to recognize the device so I can add it.

The good news, is that connecting the device back to my Windows machine seems to still work, so their description of the update is a little misleading (at least to me).